# Mysql Remote Connection Communication Failure

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea

I am trying to connect remote mysql database using jdbc driver. I am using IntelliJ first time, so I am not sure if this error blocks the communication :

```
 Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

And also I can connect to my database from any database tool using SSH connection. This is my connection code :

```
public DatabaseHelper() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://MY_SERVER_URL:3306/DB_NAME", "root", "MY_PASS");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This is the output.

```
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1117)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:350)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2393)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2430)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2215)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:813)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:399)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:334)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at com.bitirme.database.DatabaseHelper.<init>(DatabaseHelper.java:32)
    at com.bitirme.core.Fetcher.<init>(Fetcher.java:35)
    at com.bitirme.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:28)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:244)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:257)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:300)
```

I used to get this error, after i changed mysql driver version it would become fine. But this time I tried to change version, result is still the same.

**Also I am not using any firewall, or any application that blocks the database communication!**

Comment: I don't think this is the database error, because i used to connect to this database. I have not change anything also

Comment: OK bye ........ see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2840358/2310289

Comment: *And also I can connect to my database from any database tool using SSH connection*... uhm, using SSH to connect to your database doesn't mean that your DBMS is properly configured to accept connection from remote clients. When you ssh in your server, you are connecting to the dbms from `localhost`. I think you need to properly configure it.